# pinch_zoom_image_updated change main layout

Tags: flutter

Anytime `pinch_zoom_image_updated` is used to zoom on image this grey and black continer adds up:
[image]

Normally this is what it looks like:

[image]

Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting to true the argumnent constructor 'hideStatusBarWhileZooming'

Thank you

Comment: actually it was set to 'true', ive changed it to false and it works!
thanks a lot!!